# How to create and retrieve a snapshot programmatically using SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, snapshot

I'm trying to create a snapshot and pull it back out later programmatically.  I have the first part working (shown below) but I can't seem to find a way to pull this same snapshot back out later based on some unique identifier ...

```
Dim rs As ReportingService2005.ReportingService2005 = New ReportingService2005.ReportingService2005()

rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

Dim snapID = rs.CreateReportHistorySnapshot(reportname, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Render` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258532(SQL.80).aspx) accepts an optional `HistoryID` parameter:

> The unique identifier of a report history snapshot to render for the specified report. The identifier is based on the date and time the report history was created.

Curiously, that method is missing from the documentation for the 2005 and 2008 web services.

You can also specify an rs:Snapshot parameter if you're using URL rendering.